# QDBusAbstractAdaptor object does not export implemented dbus interface

Tags: qt, interface, dbus, bluez, qtdbus

I'm trying to implement a pairing agent for BlueZ v5.5 with Qt and its DBus functionality.

I have an adaptor class that is generated by the qdbusxml2cpp tool that I called PairingAgentAdaptor and a class with the implemented methods (PairingAgent) that I give as parameter on instantiation of the adaptor class.

I can register the object as a new agent and the BlueZ daemon says that my agent is registered. If I try to pair my phone with the computer, the BlueZ daemon says: "No such interface 'org.bluez.Agent1' at object path '/pairing/agent'."

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Could you please give me some hints?

Kind regards
Michael

---

*Code:*

main.cpp

```
// built using Qt 4.8.2

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <bluedevil/bluedevil.h> // schaal's port to BlueZ 5

#define AGENT_PATH "/pairing/agent"

[...]

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    PairingAgent pairingAgent;
    PairingAgentAdaptor pairingAgentAdaptor(&pairingAgent);

    bool registerSuccess = QDBusConnection::systemBus().registerObject(QString(AGENT_PATH), &pairingAgentAdaptor);

    if (registerSuccess) {
        cout << "Registered as " << AGENT_PATH << endl;
    } else {
        QDBusConnection::systemBus().unregisterObject(QString(AGENT_PATH), QDBusConnection::UnregisterTree);

        registerSuccess = QDBusConnection::systemBus().registerObject(QString(AGENT_PATH), &pairingAgentAdaptor);

        if (registerSuccess) {
            cout << "Registered as " << AGENT_PATH << " (round 2)" << endl;
        } else {
            cerr << "Registering of " << AGENT_PATH << " failed." << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    Manager* const manager = Manager::self();
    manager->registerAgent(QString(AGENT_PATH), Manager::DisplayOnly);

    return app.exec();
}
```

pairingagentadaptor.h

```
[...]

/*
 * Adaptor class for interface org.bluez.Agent1
 */
class PairingAgentAdaptor: public QDBusAbstractAdaptor {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_CLASSINFO("D-Bus Interface", "org.bluez.Agent1")
    Q_CLASSINFO("D-Bus Introspection", ""
"  <interface name=\"org.bluez.Agent1\">\n"
"    <method name=\"Release\"/>\n"
"    <method name=\"RequestPinCode\">\n"
"      <arg direction=\"in\" type=\"o\"/>\n"
"      <arg direction=\"out\" type=\"s\"/>\n"
"    </method>\n"
"    <method name=\"DisplayPinCode\">\n"
"      <arg direction=\"in\" type=\"o\"/>\n"
"      <arg direction=\"in\" type=\"s\"/>\n"
"    </method>\n"
"    <method name=\"RequestPasskey\">\n"
"      <arg direction=\"in\" type=\"o\"/>\n"
"      <arg direction=\"out\" type=\"u\"/>\n"
"    </method>\n"
"    <method name=\"DisplayPasskey\">\n"
"      <arg direction=\"in\" type=\"o\"/>\n"
"      <arg direction=\"in\" type=\"u\"/>\n"
"    </method>\n"
"    <method name=\"RequestConfirmation\">\n"
"      <arg direction=\"in\" type=\"o\"/>\n"
"      <arg direction=\"in\" type=\"u\"/>\n"
"    </method>\n"
"    <method name=\"RequestAuthorization\">\n"
"      <arg direction=\"in\" type=\"o\"/>\n"
"      <arg direction=\"in\" type=\"u\"/>\n"
"    </method>\n"
"    <method name=\"AuthorizeService\">\n"
"      <arg direction=\"in\" type=\"o\"/>\n"
"      <arg direction=\"in\" type=\"s\"/>\n"
"    </method>\n"
"    <method name=\"Cancel\"/>\n"
"  </interface>\n"
        "")
public:
    PairingAgentAdaptor(QObject *parent);
    virtual ~PairingAgentAdaptor();

public: // PROPERTIES
public Q_SLOTS: // METHODS
    void AuthorizeService(const QDBusObjectPath &in0, const QString &in1);
    void Cancel();
    void DisplayPasskey(const QDBusObjectPath &in0, uint in1);
    void DisplayPinCode(const QDBusObjectPath &in0, const QString &in1);
    void Release();
    void RequestAuthorization(const QDBusObjectPath &in0, uint in1);
    void RequestConfirmation(const QDBusObjectPath &in0, uint in1);
    uint RequestPasskey(const QDBusObjectPath &in0);
    QString RequestPinCode(const QDBusObjectPath &in0);
Q_SIGNALS: // SIGNALS
};
```

Comment: Have you used qdbusviewer to verify that the adaptor is showing up as you expected? I'm not familiar with BlueZ, but is the daemon definitely looking on the system bus and not the session bus?

Comment: org.bluez is showing up on the system bus and it recognizes my application when I register it as a new agent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got it now. :)

My first mistake:

```
PairingAgent pairingAgent;
PairingAgentAdaptor pairingAgentAdaptor(&pairingAgent);

bool registerSuccess = QDBusConnection::systemBus().registerObject(QString(AGENT_PATH), &pairingAgentAdaptor);
```

It has to be

```
bool registerSuccess = QDBusConnection::systemBus().registerObject(QString(AGENT_PATH), &pairingAgent); // NEVER the adaptor!!!
```

My second mistake: I got the wrong interface for org.bluez.Agent1. The right one is:

```
<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Object Introspection 1.0//EN" "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/introspect.dtd">
<node>
    <interface name="org.bluez.Agent1">
        <method name="Release" />
        <method name="RequestPinCode">
            <arg direction="in" type="o" />
            <arg direction="out" type="s" />
        </method>
        <method name="DisplayPinCode">
            <arg direction="in" type="o" />
            <arg direction="in" type="s" />
        </method>
        <method name="RequestPasskey">
            <arg direction="in" type="o" />
            <arg direction="out" type="u" />
        </method>
        <method name="DisplayPasskey">
            <arg direction="in" type="o" />
            <arg direction="in" type="u" />
            <arg direction="in" type="q" />
        </method>
        <method name="RequestConfirmation">
            <arg direction="in" type="o" />
            <arg direction="in" type="u" />
        </method>
        <method name="RequestAuthorization">
            <arg direction="in" type="o" />
        </method>
        <method name="AuthorizeService">
            <arg direction="in" type="o" />
            <arg direction="in" type="s" />
        </method>
        <method name="Cancel" />
    </interface>
</node>
```