# How to create / instantiate pairing agent on D-Bus with Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, dbus

I'm trying to build a Qt application for pairing / connecting bluetooth devices on a Linux device. I'm using the BlueZ API (https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc) over D-Bus as descibed in the BlueZ official site (http://www.bluez.org/page/8/).

The general procedure is described in here:
https://www.kynetics.com/docs/2018/pairing_agents_bluez/

At the moment, I can use the APIs for pairing/connecting devices without problems.

BUT I cannot figure out how to use the pairing agent.

I'm trying to follow the direction pointed out here:
[How can i set the bluetooth pin number in linux C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632755/how-can-i-set-the-bluetooth-pin-number-in-linux-c-c)

[QDBusAbstractAdaptor object does not export implemented dbus interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009732/qdbusabstractadaptor-object-does-not-export-implemented-dbus-interface)

I searched a lot on the web and there are tons of code:

https://github.com/sdemario/qt-bluez-demos

https://github.com/KDE/bluez-qt

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluez/+/froyo-release/test/agent.c

https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez/blob/master/client/agent.c

https://www.linumiz.com/bluetooth-connectdevice-without-scanning/

but, still, I can't understand how this works. There are also a lot of scripts in python out there, but I'm working with C++.

My (pseudo)-code is the following:

```
agentManager = new QDBusInterface("org.bluez","/org/bluez","org.bluez.AgentManager1",QDBusConnection::systemBus(),this);
agent = new QDBusInterface("org.bluez","/org/bluez/agent","org.bluez.Agent1",QDBusConnection::systemBus(),this);


QDBusReply<void> reply;

reply = agentManager->call("RegisterAgent", QVariant::fromValue(QDBusObjectPath(path)), capability);
if (!reply.isValid()) {
    qDebug() << reply.error().message() << reply.error().name();
}

reply = agentManager->call("RequestDefaultAgent", QVariant::fromValue(QDBusObjectPath(path)));
if (!reply.isValid()) {
    qDebug() << reply.error().message() << reply.error().name();
}

QDBusReply<QString> reply_str = agent->call("RequestPinCode", QVariant::fromValue(QDBusObjectPath(path)));
if (reply_str.isValid()) {
    pincode = reply_str.value();
} else {
    qDebug() << reply_str.error().message() << reply.error().name();
}
```

The "RegisterAgent" and "RequestDefaultAgent" calls give a valid reply, while, the "RequestPinCode" gives an error:

"Method "RequestPinCode" with signature "o" on interface "org.bluez.Agent1" doesn't exist
" "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject"

Why? What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I implemented a brand new service on D-Bus, which implements the org.bluez.Agent1 interface (at leat a part of it). Now, the code looks like this:

```
MyObject* myObject = new MyObject();
MyAdaptor* myAdaptor = new MyQDusAdaptor(myObject);

if (QDBusConnection::systemBus().registerService("org.test")) {
    qDebug() << "registerService was Succesfull!";
} else {
    qDebug() << "registerService was not Succesfull!";
}

if(QDBusConnection::systemBus().registerObject("/pairing/agent",myObject)){
    qDebug() << "registerObject was Succesfull!";
} else {
    qDebug() << "registerObject was not Succesfull!";
}

agentManager->RegisterAgent(QDBusObjectPath("/pairing/agent"),"NoInputNoOutput");
agentManager->RequestDefaultAgent(QDBusObjectPath("/pairing/agent"));
```

where the MyObject is

```
class MyObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyObject();

public Q_SLOTS:
    QString RequestPinCode(const QDBusObjectPath &in0);
};


MyObject::MyObject() {

}
QString MyObject::RequestPinCode(const QDBusObjectPath& in0)
{
    qDebug() << "MyObject" << in0.path();


    QString str = "2974";
    return str;
}
```

and the adaptor is

```
class MyQDusAdaptor: public QDBusAbstractAdaptor
{

    Q_OBJECT
    Q_CLASSINFO("D-Bus Interface", "org.bluez.Agent1")
    Q_CLASSINFO("D-Bus Introspection", ""
                                                                         "  <interface name=\"org.bluez.Agent1\">\n"
                                                                         "    <method name=\"RequestPinCode\">\n"
                                                                         "      <arg direction=\"in\" type=\"o\"/>\n"
                                                                         "      <arg direction=\"out\" type=\"s\"/>\n"
                                                                         "    </method>\n"
                                                                         "  </interface>\n"
                                                                         "")

public:
        MyQDusAdaptor(QObject *parent);
        virtual ~MyQDusAdaptor();

public: // PROPERTIES
public Q_SLOTS: // METHODS
        QString RequestPinCode(const QDBusObjectPath &in0);
};


MyQDusAdaptor::MyQDusAdaptor(QObject* parent) : QDBusAbstractAdaptor(parent) {

    setAutoRelaySignals(true);
}

MyQDusAdaptor::~MyQDusAdaptor() {

}

QString MyQDusAdaptor::RequestPinCode(const QDBusObjectPath& in0)
{
    qDebug() << "MyQDusAdaptor" << in0.path();

    QString out0;
         QMetaObject::invokeMethod(parent(), "RequestPinCode", Q_RETURN_ARG(QString, out0), Q_ARG(QDBusObjectPath, in0));
         return out0;
}
```

When I try to pair a smartphone, the application freezes for ca 30s, I recieve the following error message:

"Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken." "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply"

and only after that the smartphone ask to insert a PIN.

I think that has to be done asynchronously. Any tips?

Comment: I'm using qdbusviewer for exploring the objects, and I cannot find the agent

Comment: If you want to implement the UI where the user e.g. inputs a pincode or accepts a connection, you have to actually write a D-Bus service that implements the whole org.bluez.Agent1 interface.

Comment: @JussiKukkonen So, I cannot add the interface to the already existent org.bluez service? I have to instantiate a brand new service?

Comment: Now I'm trying to figure out how qt does the job (https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtconnectivity/src/bluetooth/bluez/agent_p.h.html). I cannot use the qt bluetooth module, because I have to work with Qt 4.8

Comment: If you want to make your own agent then yes: you do have to implement a  service that implements Agent. Bluez will then call the methods on your service when information from your agent is required.

Comment: @JussiKukkonen ok, I created a new service which implements the RequestPinCode method from org.bluez.Agent1. Now the problem is that the application locks when I try to pair a device (my guess is that is waiting for a response from the smartphone, but the smartphone asks for insert PIN oly after the timeout is over). Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I managed to make it work. :) I just made the call to "Pair" asynchronous with callWithCallback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now it works. The way to do it is explained in [QDBusAbstractAdaptor object does not export implemented dbus interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009732/qdbusabstractadaptor-object-does-not-export-implemented-dbus-interface?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Details of the implementation are in the last **EDIT** of this question. The last thing to to is to implement the "Pair" method on the Device1 interface asynchronously with callWithCallback:

```
void cBluetoothDevice::Pair() {

    QList<QVariant> args;
    args.clear();

    device->callWithCallback("Pair",args, this, SLOT(PairSlot(QDBusMessage)));
}
```

where device is a QDBusInterface*

Comment: can you modify the question to add a working example with the content of this answer?